# Qt Creator - Can I Work On One Package Without Building Other Packages In Same Catkin Workspace?

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I'm having some issues using Qt Creator as an IDE for ROS:

If I have multiple packages within a catkin workspace, and I open just ONE of the packages' CMakeLists.txt file within Qt Creator, Qt Creator still sees the remaining packages in the catkin workspace. When building/running, Qt Creator will try to try to build all executables and then I have the option to run any of the executables in the catkin workspace.

Can I work on separate packages in isolation with Qt Creator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97631/qt-creator---can-i-work-on-one-package-without-building-other-packages-in-same-catkin-workspace?/) by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2013-11-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To anyone with the same question, I found that you can select what you build manually in the Projects tab of Qt Creator. So, yes, you can build only a single package. However I have not found a way to run CMake on a single package/project in isolation.

---

Originally posted by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) with karma: 293 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0